# Get first record change timestamp when grouped by two columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that tracks versions history.I need to get the record the shows the first version change timestamp to the most recent version.

EDIT: Added more records to illustrate what I am looking for.
For example

```
id  version     timestamp
(123, 1.5, '2015-03-28 08:21:04'),
(123, 1.5, '2015-03-28 07:21:04'),
(123, 1.5, '2015-03-27 07:21:04'), <-- Latest version,first change for id 123
(123, 1.2, '2015-03-22 12:58:24'),
(123, 1.2, '2015-03-21 13:32:05'),
(123, 1.0, '2015-03-21 09:18:37'),
(123, 1.0, '2015-03-20 04:44:59'),
(234, 1.5, '2016-10-15 23:08:09'), <-- Latest version,first change for id 234
(345, 1.5, '2016-10-10 15:18:09'),
(345, 1.5, '2016-09-02 21:30:00'),
(345, 1.5, '2016-09-01 21:30:00'),
(345, 1.5, '2016-08-02 21:30:00'), <-- Latest version,first change for id 345
(345, 1.0, '2016-07-02 21:30:00')
```

Expected output

```
id  version     timestamp
(123, 1.5, '2015-03-27 07:21:04')
(234, 1.5, '2016-10-15 23:08:09')
(345, 1.5, '2016-08-02 21:30:00')
```

I was able to get this by using temp tables.I get the min(dt_create) for each id and version and store it in a temp table.Then I get the max date from this table for each id and then join it again to get the version.Is there a better way to do this?

```
create table #temp_version
(
       id varchar(22) NOT NULL,
       version varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       dt_create datetime NOT null
)

insert into #temp_version   
select  id,version,min(dt_create) as dt_create
from [version_history] (nolock) 
group by id,version

create table #temp_min_date
(
      id varchar(22) NOT NULL,
      dt_create datetime NOT null
)

insert into #temp_min_date
select id,max(dt_create) 
from #temp_version
group by id

select a.id,a.version,a.dt_create 
from #temp_version a
join #temp_date b on a.id = b.id and 
a.dt_create=b.dt_create 

drop table #temp_date
drop table #temp_version
```

Comment: using `row_number()` together with `over()`

Comment: How is that the latest version for ID 123? It's square in the middle of the date range. That makes no sense to me

Comment: @scsimon 1.5 is the latest version for 123 and the first timestamp that reflects it is 2015-03-27 07:21:04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query without any joins:

```
select
    id, [version], dt_create
from (
    select
        id,
        [version],
        rank() over (partition by id order by [version] desc, dt_create desc) as rnk,
        min(dt_create) over (partition by id, [version]) as dt_create
    from @history
) res
where
    rnk = 1
```

And there the whole query with your test data:

```
declare @history table(id varchar(22), [version] varchar(50), dt_create datetime);

insert into @history(id, [version], dt_create) values
    ('123', '1.5', '2015-03-28 08:21:04'),
    ('123', '1.5', '2015-03-28 07:21:04'),
    ('123', '1.5', '2015-03-27 07:21:04'),
    ('123', '1.2', '2015-03-22 12:58:24'),
    ('123', '1.2', '2015-03-21 13:32:05'),
    ('123', '1.0', '2015-03-21 09:18:37'),
    ('123', '1.0', '2015-03-20 04:44:59'),
    ('234', '1.5', '2016-10-15 23:08:09'),
    ('345', '1.5', '2016-10-10 15:18:09'),
    ('345', '1.5', '2016-09-02 21:30:00'),
    ('345', '1.5', '2016-09-01 21:30:00'),
    ('345', '1.5', '2016-08-02 21:30:00'),
    ('345', '1.0', '2016-07-02 21:30:00')

select
    id, [version], dt_create
from (
    select
        id,
        [version],
        rank() over (partition by id order by [version] desc, dt_create desc) as rnk,
        min(dt_create) over (partition by id, [version]) as dt_create
    from @history
) res
where
    rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks,this works for the sample.Will test it out and update.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without CTE or subquery:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES 
    id,
    version,
    dt_create = timestamp
FROM [version_history] 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY version desc, timestamp)
```

Comment: won't this return `2015-03-21 12:58:24.730` for `Id = 123`

Comment: @Prdp There are no such value in expected result

Comment: That's a nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function with a sub-query or CTE. Note that in your expected output, for ID 123 you didn't select the first instance... just the one with the minimum TIME, without consideration to the date. If that's what you really want, then you just need to use the time portion in the order by. i.e. `(partition by id order by cast(timestamp as time))`

```
select t.id, t.version, t.timestamp
from
YourTable t
inner join
(select
    id,
    version,
    timestamp,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp) as rn
from YourTable) x on x.id = t.id and x.timestamp = t.timestamp and x.version = t.version
where x.rn = 1
```

Comment: This will also give 123 1.0         2015-03-21 12:58:24.730 in the result because for a given version it has 1 row and would get a row number 1.

Comment: what do you mean if you change the data it doesn't work @inquisitive_mind?

Comment: My table has millions of records.If I add few more records, it will give me incorrect record. Tried for this (123, 1.5, '2015-03-28 08:21:04'),
    (123, 1.5, '2015-03-28 07:21:04'),
    (123, 1.5, '2015-03-27 07:21:04'),
    (123, 1.0, '2015-03-21 12:58:24'),
    (123, 1.0, '2015-03-20 12:58:24'),
    (123, 1.2, '2015-03-22 12:58:24'),
    (123, 1.2, '2015-03-21 12:58:24'),
    (234, 1.5, '2016-10-15 23:08:09'),
    (345, 1.5, '2016-10-10 15:18:09'),
    (345, 1.5, '2016-09-02 21:30:00'),
    (345, 1.5, '2016-09-01 21:30:00'),
    (345, 1.5, '2016-08-02 21:30:00')

Comment: what's incorrect about it? As i explained in my answer, I think your expected results were incorrect. Can you explain what is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
create table #temp_version
(
       id varchar(22) NOT NULL,
       version varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       dt_create datetime NOT null
)

insert into #temp_version values
(123, 1.5, '2015-03-28 08:21:04'),(123, 1.5, '2015-03-28 07:21:04'),(123, 1.5, '2015-03-27 07:21:04')
,(123, 1.0, '2015-03-21 12:58:24'),(123, 1.0, '2015-03-20 12:58:24'),(123, 1.2, '2015-03-22 12:58:24')
,(123, 1.2, '2015-03-21 12:58:24'),(234, 1.5, '2016-10-15 23:08:09'),(345, 1.5, '2016-10-10 15:18:09')
,(345, 1.5, '2016-09-02 21:30:00'),(345, 1.5, '2016-09-01 21:30:00'),(345, 1.5, '2016-08-02 21:30:00');

select top(1) with ties id, version, dt_create
from (
    select *, lag(version) over(partition by id order by dt_create) prev
    from #temp_version 
    ) t
where version != prev or prev is null -- first change
--  recent version 
order by row_number() over(partition by id order by dt_create desc);
-- or may be .. order by version .. depending on what is "recent"
```